# I can exec my stored procedure in SQL Server Management Studio but webservice can not

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, web-services, stored-procedures

I have a webservice method that executes a tabular stored procedure. This `sp` takes 1 minute to be executed completely. I call that webservice method remotely and get results.

In normal situations everything is OK and I get results successfully.

But when the server is busy the webservice can not execute that `sp` (I tested it in SQL Profiler and nothing comes to profiler) but I can execute that `sp` manually in SQL Server Management Studio.

When I restart SQL Server, the problem is solved and the webservice can execute `sp`.

Why in busy situations webservice can not execute `sp` but I can do it in SQL Server Management Studio?

How this situation can be explained? How can I solve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Execute `sp_who` and see what is happening; my guess is that it is being blocked - perhaps your "isolation level" is different between SSMS and the web-service.

Equally, it could well be that the connection's `SET` options are different between SSMS and the web-service, which can lead to certain changes in behavior - for example, computed-stored-indexed values are ***very*** susceptible to `SET` options: if the caller's options aren't compatible with the options that were set when the column was created, then it can be forced to table-scan them, recalculating them all, instead of using the pre-indexed values. This also applies to hoisted xml values.

A final consideration is parameter sniffing; if the cache gets generated for `yourproc 'abc'` which has very different stats than `yourproc 'def'`, then it can run very bad query plans. The `optimize for / unknown` hint can help with this.